# How to Understand My Ruby Environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am having some path issues and trying to understand how to read and match the paths.  Here is what I am doing:

```
$PATH
bash: /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/agenadinik/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

And then I am trying to see what is in my ruby environment:

```
$gem environment
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:4: 
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /home/agenadinik/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

What I don't understand is which of my paths need to be matched up in my ruby environment and the $PATH

Also, is my $PATH pretty much what is set in my /home/username/.bashrc file?
What is usually the path of the Ruby executable that I need to point to?

Also, doing which ruby returns this:

```
$ which ruby
/home/agenadinik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using RVM. You have many available Ruby paths. When you source the RVM scripts in your `bashrc` it will modify your path. Every time you `rvm use XXX` it will modify your path to reflect the new version of Ruby and update all of the bins to match that version. If you are trying to make a proper shebang for a Ruby script you should use `env`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This will find the current `ruby` executable in your path.

Comment: actually doing "env ruby" just makes the system hang.  :-/ Why would that happen?

Comment: That is what happens when you run `ruby`. The interpreter is reading stdin.